# WebRequest.GetResponseAsync() fails where WebRequest.GetResponse() succeeds

Tags: c#, webrequest

i have the following OperationContract setup which works fine sychronously but fails to do anything when called asynchronously from a client:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "startExport", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 void Export();
```

The method 'Export()' is setup for testing as follows:

```
 public void Export()
 {
     var aProc = Process.Start("LongRunning.exe"));

     aProc.WaitForExit();

     //Trigger a message on the server interface to say the exe has completed
 }
```

The server is setup as follows:

```
WebServiceHost _oHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(DataService), new Uri("http://localhost:7000/"));

var oRestBinding = new WebHttpBinding
{
   CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
   OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
   ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
   SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
};

_oHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ExternalComms), oRestBinding, "http://localhost:7000/");
```

Does anyone have any idea why the Export method can only be triggered with WebRequest.GetResponse() and not WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()? What i need is a REST call to the server that does not block the client.

I've also tried the following at the client but with the same result as WebRequest.GetResponseAsync() (the server method 'Export()' is not triggered):

```
const string url = @"http://localhost:7000/startExport";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { request.GetResponse(); });
```

Comment: Could you add Exception information with StackTrace?

Comment: How do you signal when response is completed?

Comment: i don't want to, i need to just fire and forget. The server should run the exe and wait but the client doesn't need to know about it.

Comment: Well at least you have the 'and forget' bit working :)    If you lack a better solution, make a new thread that calls it the regular way, then terminates.